# Python is saving the xlsx file in a different folder then declared

Tags: python

Hello it try to save a xlsx file in a specific folder, but it keeps saving a new file in the folder before the last one, so not "Workshop_3". Where is the mistake?

```
 import os



    file_name = 'Rechnung_' + Vorname + Nachname +'.xlsx'
    file_path =os.path.join('C:','Users','Robin','Desktop','Y ss19','Workshop_3', datei_name)
    wb.save(file_name)
```

Comment: Answered your question, hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting a variable `file_path`, but you are not using it:

```
file_name = 'Rechnung_' + Vorname + Nachname +'.xlsx'
file_path = os.path.join('C:','Users','Robin','Desktop','Y ss19','Workshop_3', file_name)
wb.save( file_path ) # <- !!!
```

You should also use `file_name` instead of `datei_name` when building the path, because `datei_name` is not defined in your sample code.

The reason python is saving the file to the parent directory instead, is *probably* because it's the current working directory.

Comment: Leads me to wonder what `datei_name` is and why `file_name` wasn't used in the second line

Comment: @Jab good observation, I mentioned in the answer that ``datei_name`` is not defined.

Comment: @Jab, that was a typo sorry. I translated datei to file from german. This solution works perfect thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're saving to file_name, you want to save to file_path

```
import os

file_name = 'Rechnung_' + Vorname + Nachname +'.xlsx'
file_path =os.path.join('C:','Users','Robin','Desktop','Y ss19','Workshop_3', datei_name)
wb.save(file_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should also pass the **path** along with the file name while invoking `wb.save()`

```
wb.save(file_path + file_name)
```